# Как преобразовать текст html в html сущности в React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть код на React.js, который получает с сервера html-контент. Вот он:

```
    clicked: function(index){
    var server = 'http://myserver.org';
    var page   = this.props.items[index].page;
    var url    = server + "/pages/" + page + ".html";

    this.serverRequest = $.get(url, function(result){

        this.setState({
            content: result
        });

    }.bind(this));
},
```

Затем, я пытаюсь его отобразить в браузере таким образом:

```
render: function() {

    return (
        <div>Content: {this.state.content}</div>
    );
}
```

Этот код работает, но вместо красивого html-контента, который содержится в полученных файлах, он выводит их текстовое представление. Как преобразовать это все в красивые html-сущности?

Или, что в моем подходе не так, если я изначально выбрал ложное направление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. При этом он принимает объект в виде `{__html:...}`.
Но фейсбук не одобряет данный подход, так как он не безопасен в плане XSS-атак.

```
function createMarkup() { return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а какой подход facebook одобряет?

Comment: @Razzwan передавать через json конкретные данные и уже на клиенте рендерить. Передаете данные, в зависимости от каких-то параметров рендерите тот шаблон, который вам необходим.

Comment: Предположим, у меня в проекте 2000 разных видов, предположим, у меня на сайте предоставляется возможность пользователям изменять свой вид так, как они захотят. Я не хочу все эти виды загружать сразу - я хочу их подргузить ajax-ом по мере необходимости. Как в этом случае поступить?

Comment: Ну вот как раз для этого и есть dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Мне другие варианты в голову не приходят.